# Solution of recurrence relation for roots having multiplicity $ \ge 1 $

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

If there is a recurrence relation of the form $ a_n = c_1 a_{n-1} + 
c_2 a_{n-2}+ ... + c_k a_{n-k} $, then if b is a non zero complex root of 
the recurrence relation with multiplicity t, $t \ge 1 $,  then $ b, nb, n^2 , ... , n^{t-1}b $ are all solution of the recurrence relation.

I want to prove this, so I can denote the characteristic equation of this relation  as $$ p(x) =  x^k + c_1 x^{k-1} + c_2x^{k-2} + .... + c_k $$  Then p(x) = $ (x - b)^ t q(x) $, where q(x) is of degree k-t. I dont know how solve after this, should it be done like with induction as where we first prove that b is true, then show if $ n^ {t-1} b $ is a solution then 
$ n^t $ is a solution too where $ t \lt k $  or is there some other way to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof goes by using generating functions. Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, and take your recurrence with initial values $a_0$ through $a_{k - 1}$. Shift indices to get:

$\begin{align}
a_{n + k}
  = c_1 a_{n + k - 1} + \dotsb + c_k a_n
\end{align}$

Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$ and get:

$\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + k} z^n
  = c_1 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + k - 1} z^n
     + \dotsb
     + c_k \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
\end{align}$

Recognize the sums here:

$\begin{align}
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z - \dotsb - a_{k - 1} z^{k - 1}}{z^k}
  = c_1 \frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z - \dotsb - a_{k - 2} z^{k - 2}}{z^{k - 1}}
      + \dotsb
      + c_k A(z)
\end{align}$

Solving this for $A(z)$ gives a rational function of the form:

$\begin{align}
A(z) = \frac{P(z)}{1 - c_1 z - \dotsb - c_k z^k}
\end{align}$

The polynomial $P(z)$ depends on the initial values, and is of degree less than $k$. It is known that such can be split into [partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). A zero $\rho$ of multiplicity $m$ of the denominator gives rise to terms:

$\begin{align}
\frac{a_m}{(z - \rho)^m} + \dotsb + \frac{a_1}{z - \rho}
\end{align}$

Now, by the generalized [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) we know that if $r$ is a positive integer:

$\begin{align}
(1 - \rho^{-1} z)^{-r}
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \binom{-r}{n} \rho^{-n} z^n \\
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n + r - 1}{r - 1} \rho^{-n} z^n
\end{align}$

The solution of the recurrence is the coefficient of $z^n$ in the sum of the coefficients in each term of the partial fraction expansion.
As the binomial coefficient in this expansion is a polynomial of degree $r - 1$ in $n$, the sum of the terms for $\rho$ add up to a polynomial of degree $m - 1$ in $n$ by $\rho^{-n}$, whose coefficients depend on the initial values.

Comment: Here I offer my understanding of this answer if someone is one newbie as me when I read this post. This post has one specific [application](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/752184/1059606) with one specific example. 1. $\frac{a_m}{(z - \rho)^m} + \dotsb + \frac{a_1}{z - \rho}$ is due to: in the characteristic equation $r^k-c_1 r^{k-1}-\cdots-c_k=0$, divide both sides by $r^k$, then $z=r^{-1}$, so the repeated root $b$ in $(x-b)^t$ means $\rho=b^{-1}$. Then the above has $\rho^{-n}$ in its final equation of $a_n$.

Comment: 2. $\frac{a_m}{(z - \rho)^m}$ can be changed to $\frac{a_m'}{(1 - \rho^{-1}z)^m}$, so the above calculates $(1 - \rho^{-1}z)^{-r}$. Please point out errors if any. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has another solution in this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20231225104031/https://staff.cdms.westernsydney.edu.au/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/zhuhan/dmath/dm_readall.cgi?page=22) "Derivation Hints for the Main Theorem"

It is based on iterative usage of $\triangle-\lambda$ to decrease the order $s$ of $n^s$ in the solution $(\sum_{i=0}^s b_in^i)\cdot \lambda^n$ where $s$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda$.

$(\triangle-\lambda)^s$ can work as the normal polynomial because of the binomial theorem. For example, $(\triangle^2-2\lambda\triangle+\lambda^2)n^i\lambda^n=(\triangle-\lambda)^2n^i\lambda^n$