# How to solve $f(n) = 6f(n-1) - 9f(n-2)$ for $n \ge 2$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The method I found for solving recursive equations starts like this:

First, I express the equation with the help of polynomials $q$, so

$$q^n = 6q^{n-1} - 9q^{n-2}.$$

This is equivalent to

$$q^2 = 6q - 9,$$

which can be solved with the $p-q$-formula.

The goal is to solve this system of linear equations:

$$f(0) = a_1 + a_2 = 0$$
$$f(1) = a_1q_1 + a_2q_2 = 1$$

with $q_1$ and $q_2$ being the solutions that I receive with the help of the $p-q$-formula. But: The $p-q$-formula only yields one solution in this case, which is $q_1 = 3$, and hence, I don't know how to go further from here.

Comment: When we have a second order homogeneous linear recurrence relation with repeated roots, the general solution is given by:
$$f(n)=c_1 \lambda^n+c_2 n\lambda^n$$
Where $\lambda$ is the root of the quadratic characteristic equation. For an $n$-th order linear homogeneous recurrence, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54862/how-do-i-resolve-a-recurrence-relation-when-the-characteristic-equation-has-fewe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

As $q^2-6q+9=(q-3)^2,$

$$f(n)=(an+b)3^n$$  where $a,b$ are arbitrary constants to be determined from the initial conditions

Answer (score 0):

It's just $f(n)=n3^{n-1}$, but I like the following way:
$$f(n)-3f(n-1)=3(f(n-1)-3(f(n-2)),$$
which gives $$f(n)-3f(n-1)=3^{n-1}$$ and from here we obtain:
$$f(n)-3f(n-1)=3^{n-1}$$
$$3f(n-1)-9f(n-2)=3^{n-1}$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$3^{n-1}f(1)-3^nf(0)=3^{n-1},$$
which after summing gives
$$f(n)-3^nf(0)=n3^{n-1}$$ or
$$f(n)=n3^{n-1}.$$